# use of r1.question when using google sheets api

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am using the documentation found at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs in order to use the google sheets api in my node.js application. For reference, the code I'm using from the page is as below:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
 * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
 */
function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
    range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const rows = res.data.values;
    if (rows.length) {
      console.log('Name, Major:');
      // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
      rows.map((row) => {
        console.log(`${row[0]}, ${row[4]}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No data found.');
    }
  });
}
```

At the line where it says `rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {` I get the feeling that I'm supposed to input something, but I never see any obvious prompt to enter any kind of code, and thus I do not enter anything and my code goes to `return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);` and I apparently never get an access token. How exactly do I enter this code, and where do I get this code from?

EDIT: Detailed flow for replicating bug.

I have the following requires at the top of my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
```

Below is the route which I first access in the browser in order to initiate the process.

```
app.get("/test", function (req,res) {

    // If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
    const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

    // Load client secrets from a local file.
    fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
        // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
    });

    /**
     * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
     * given callback function.
     * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
     * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
     */
    function authorize(credentials, callback) {
        //const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
        var client_secret = credentials.web.client_secret;
        var client_id = credentials.web.client_id;
        var redirect_uris = credentials.web.redirect_uris;
        const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

        // Check if we have previously stored a token.
        fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
     * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
     * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
     */
    function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
        const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: SCOPES,
        });
        console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout,
        });
        rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
            rl.close();
            oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
     * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
     */
    function listMajors(auth) {
        const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
            range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
        }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            const rows = res.data.values;
            if (rows.length) {
            console.log('Name, Major:');
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            rows.map((row) => {
                console.log(`${row[0]}, ${row[4]}`);
            });
            } else {
            console.log('No data found.');
            }
        });
    }
    
})
```

When I access this route, the browser tries to load to something, but never gets there. In the debug console I get a prompt saying "Authorize this app by visiting this url: ..." and I go to the given url in the browser. I am already signed into google, so I am given a list of accounts to choose from where the browser says "Choose an account to continue to quickstart." I choose my google account, and then I get the "this app isn't verified screen", so I click "Advanced" towards the bottom of the screen, after which a "Go to Quickstart (unsafe)" link appears. I click this link, and then I seemingly go back to the previous oauth screen where I was given a list of accounts, except a prompt now appears asking to Grant Quickstart permission to view your google spreadsheets. I click "Allow", and then I am redirected to a page which looks similar to the previous Oath screen, except it's asking me to confirm my choices, make sure you trust quickstart etc., so I click Allow once again and I am finally redirected to the page I specified that I would go to by my redirect url. However, in my working directory I can never see token.json, and I never see the "Enter the code from that page here: " in the terminal (I am using VSCode and the terminal is set as windows powershell). When I try to enter the code I get from the url parameters (from the redirect page at the end) I get the error I mentioned before.

Comment: In that case, can you see the URL at `Authorize this app by visiting this url:`? If you can see it, please access to the URL using your browser. By this, the login screen is opened when you didn't login to Google. When you log in to Google, you can see the authorization screen for authorizing the scopes (in your case, it's `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`.) When you authorize it, you can see the code. Please put the code to the terminal by copying and pasting it. By this, the access token can be retrieved by the script and you can use Sheets API.

Comment: When I authorise using my google account, I am redirected to the url that I specified when making the project, it's given as ```http://localhost:1234/testapiredirect?code=*insert_code_here*&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly``` - when I paste the code itself into the terminal after authorising I get ```You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.``` as an unexpected token error - would you be familiar with this, and know of a fix?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your replying, `*insert_code_here*` is the code. When I put it to `Enter the code from that page here:` in the terminal, the access token can be retrieved and create the file of `token.json`. So unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? if you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I'm actually not even seeing the "Enter the code from that page here: " in the terminal - I will get back to you with a reproducible example shortly

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to wait for it.

Comment: I have provided the edit, let me know if you need more info - would it be because I haven't installed something via npm yet?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I have questions. 1. How do you run the script? 2. What is your terminal and OS you are using? 3. What is your `credentials.json` for? For example, it's for web application and for desktop and so on?

Comment: 1. In vscode, I click run, then start debugging
2. Terminal is in vscode as powershell
3. I'm not sure how to get this information but if i recall correctly i selected web server application when creating the project

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your information in your replying, for example, when you directly run the script at the PowerShell like `node filename.js`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221030/discussion-between-user11508332-and-tanaike).

Comment: Could you try running this in the windows console rather than in VSCode Powershell's console? Also, is the account you got for generating the ```credentials.json``` the same one your are using to authorise to obtain the ```token.json```? And what is the exact detailed error you are getting? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Unfortunately I've only had success in starting the application from within VSCode - all other attempts from command prompt, using node . etc. have all failed. The accounts are the same, and the error is that I'm not seeing the "'Enter the code from that page here: '" at all

Comment: So, all the previous steps work accordingly apparently right? **Is the account you are using for authorising in the browser the same you used to get the credentials?** I need this info to reproduce as acccuratelly as possible

Comment: Yes all the previous steps work right. The account I'm using for authorising in the browser is the same as the one i used to get the credentials.

Comment: Hi ! Unfortunatelly I could not reproduce as for me it worked fine. Did you get to the ```Sign in```  browser screen which says ```Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:```? The ```token.json``` file should be generated after you input that into your console. Also,if you strictly follow the **Quickstart example** are you getting the same issues (i.e, same piece of code and when selecting ```Enable Sheets API``` choosing Desktop version) ?